# Pairing possibilities in a game with each board has 3 peoples

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose there are 9 people to play a certain game. Each board of this game is composed by 3 people. They each find their opponents and start to play. How many possibilities are there for how they are matched up, assuming that order doesn't matter?

i'm struggling to see how solve this. So, we have 3 boards with 3 people playing, then i tried $\dfrac{9!}{(2\cdot3)!}$ but this seems wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting the first board you have: $\frac{9!}{6!3!}$, because you have 9 to choose from. You will only select 3, that is the $\frac{9!}{6!}$ part, then (1,2,3), (2,1,3), (2,3,1), (3,2,1), (3,1,2), (1,3,2) is the same group, that is $3!$. Then you have only 6 people to choose from, so it becomes $\frac{6!}{3!3!}$ for the same reason. Then, the 3 left will form a group. So the answer is $\frac{9!}{6!3!}\frac{6!}{3!3!}$.